# Blazor + RPC workaround

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr, blazor

I believe that Blazor is a very cool thing. But, as I understand, a lot has not been realized yet. I would like to start using it, despite the fact that this is a pilot project. In this regard, I have a question: how can I make any RPC bundle? As I understand it, the .NET implementation of SignalR can not be used, but are there any workarounds? Thank you
UPD: https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/20

Comment: @mjwills I meant a connection between client and server. Client->Rpc function on server and server->Rpc function on client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would wait for the release of 0.4.0: https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/milestone/7

In this release support for SignalR is included, which the Blazor team is actively working on right now: https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/issues/20

I think that any workaround would require to create your own Javascript interop, which is much more work than waiting on SignalR support.

Comment: Can you make an assumption, how soon will this happen?

Comment: @FoxPro by the end of June (that's an estimate)

Comment: @MartinH do you know, are there any ways to help blazor developers?

Comment: @FoxPro you can help by contributing or suggesting new features, finding bugs etc. https://github.com/aspnet/Blazor/blob/dev/CONTRIBUTING.md

Comment: 09 June 2018: Moving out of 0.5.0, because the SignalR client is now being taken on by some folks in the Blazor community.